# How do I check that the WatchKit App is closed or terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I have BLE connection in my app and when the user quitted or the app become deactivated, I need to disconnect the connection. So I have to know if there is any method like **“watchAppWillTerminate“** or something in WKExtensionDelegate.

The other thing is should I check this event from the "**AppDelegate**" or "**ExtensionDelegate**"?

*P.S: The method "applicationWillResignActive" is not suitable for this issue because it is just for temporary interruptions.*

Comment: I am already using the WKExtensionDelegate. I couldn't find any method about terminating the app. This is the question I asked.

Comment: How about applicationDidEnterBackground()?